# "Bridge the problems" - is it correct?

Tags: idioms

Is it correct to say bridge the problems? Is it a commonly used expression?

I'd like to use it to express that the person I'm talking with should solve the problems.

Comment: Instead of being correct, it is not even wrong.

Comment: This question – and others like it – would probably be a better fit for [ell.SE].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Bridge the problems" would typically mean that you weren't seeking to solve them, rather you wanted to find workarounds to get around (or over) the issues.  For example:

> Dave's car and bike were both broken but, by getting the train, he had bridged his transportation problems.

Ideally, if the problem needs to be corrected then you should be more explicit and say something like "solve the problems", "fix the problems" or "address the problems".

Answer (score 4):

The more common expression is "bridge the gap." In this context, the "gap" refers to a problem.

It's possible to "bridge the problem," (assuming the problem needs a bridge), but this sounds like something of a mixed metaphor.

Comment: I agree. We may not often talk about "bridging problems;" however, when talking about problems, we _do_ commonly say, "We'll cross that bridge when we get to it." So I suppose the noun "bridge" can be used as a metaphor to refer to some unspecified way of solving a generic problem.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from Ste's suggestion, you can also use [bridge the divide/gap](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/bridge_2). It means to reduce the differences between two things or people.

*Bridge the problems* is just too awkward.